# How do i change keybinding in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to know how to change the run key binding from ctrl+shift+b to f9
but I can't find whats the command name for it.

Answer (score 4):

preferences->key bindings - user

```
[
    { "keys": ["f9"], "command": "build" }
]
```

Comment: I only see preferences -> key bindings not the user, where is user?

Answer (score 4):

The answers are correct, you just need to confirm your binding by actually executing the new binding you've made. At least that's what's worked for me so:

1. Go to "Preferences" -> "Key Bindings"
2. Type in the following in the right hand window.

```py
[
    { "keys": ["f9"], "command": "build" }
]
```

3. Press F9 on your keyboard to confirm.

It seems that the left side window is like it's own little console that needs to "build" the new key binding. I guess the execution adds the new key binding to the key bindings dictionary just like when you run a normal command in python. After the "script" is executed, the variable is added and can be used from now on.

Comment: For sublime text 3, by far this is the best answer. After I add custom keys at OSX, it created a file called Default(OSX).sublime-keymap file J.Doe said at the folder /Users/<myname>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User

Answer (score 0):

On the menu, go to "Preferences" -> "Run key bindings"

A new window opens with the standard settings on the left and a custom setting on the right.

Give your new entry to override default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ "keys": ["f9"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Run"} },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": true} },

Thanks!